# Npm multiple registries for a single scope, defined in multiple files

Tags: npm

Currently, in my project `.npmrc` I have the following and that works fine

```
//private tfs server
@scope:registry=http://server:8080/tfs/
//locally hosted server
@scope:registry=http://localhost:4873/
always-auth=true
```

I wanted to move `@scope:registry=http://localhost:4873/` out of the file as I am the only one running a local npm repository and I don't want to accidentally check it in.

It looks like npm overwrites registry entries, which makes sense if they are key-value pairs. However this puts me in an awkward spot.

To summarise: I would like to have multiple registries for a single scope, defined in different files.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like [Node config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) to do this kind of hierarchical configuration.

> Node-config organizes hierarchical configurations for your app
>   deployments.
>
> It lets you define a set of default parameters, and extend them for
>   different deployment environments (development, qa, staging,
>   production, etc.).

This way you can have a default.json with your dev configs, and create a production.json with your prod settings.

Then start your app server:

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production
$ node my-app.js
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The work around I used, at the time I believe, was to simply point my local npm repository (I was using verdaccio in a docker container) to the main npm repository. That way I was only pointing to one. I don't think there's a way to get npm itself to do this natively.

Comment: Yes, I believe you'll have to come up with something similar to what I described. Hope it helps!